# What is the best way to re-write the same logic?

Tags: c#

```
if ((ddl1.SelectedValue == "1") || (ddl1.SelectedValue == "100"))
{
    if (Fee > 0)
    { 
        Messages += " [Please the check fee and ddl1 type selected] "; 
    }
}
else if ((ddl1.SelectedValue == "2") || (ddl1.SelectedValue == "200"))
{
    if (Fee == 0)
    { 
        Messages += " [Please the check fee and ddl1 type selected] "; 
    }
}
```

//How to re-write the same logic in the most concise way?

Comment: A word of warning would be to avoid using `.StartsWith` to pull a Windows 9.  The best improvement for your code would be to format+indent it, though.

Comment: Probably best asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: you can write a `switch case statement` that would handle the value as a string like doing a range are you familiar with how to check 2 values in a case statement without using an if statement..? assign the SelectedValue.ToString()` to a variable and do the case off of that

Comment: How big is this else-if chain? Does each piece of the chain only check two values?

Comment: I'm with MethodMan - switch is much clearer here.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (((ddl1.SelectedValue == "1" || ddl1.SelectedValue == "100") && Fee > 0) ||
    ((ddl1.SelectedValue == "2" || ddl1.SelectedValue == "200") && Fee == 0 ))
{
    Messages += " [Please the check fee and ddl1 type selected] ";
}
```

The innermost the parentheses are optional and for clarify to the reader and not compilation.

If you are absolutely certain that `SelectedValue` will never be anything other than 1, 100, 2 or 200, you can further consolidate `(ddl1.SelectedValue == "1" || ddl1.SelectedValue == "100")` to `ddl1.SelectedValue.StartsWith("1")`. If selected values contains other values or is total domain is subject to change, StartsWith becomes fragile.

Comment: I'd put the Fee conditions first, so that they short-circuit first. You'll potentially do 2 less checks by reordering there.

Comment: I probably would as well if it were a green field project. However, leaving the fee check last more closely honors the original code's structure. 

If I were going to optimize the code, the first thing I'd do is remove the string concatenation, which is going to cause a much larger time sink than a few comparisons. Granted, the fact that those are string comparisons really bug me.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] ValidValues = {"1", "100", "2", "200"};
if(Fee >= 0){
    Messages += Array.IndexOf(ValidValues, ddl1.SelectedValue) == -1 ? "" : " [Please the check fee and ddl1 type selected] ";
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this honors the spirit of the fee checks. Per the code in the OP, *presumably* it is not valid to show a message for values 1 and 100 if the Fee is less than or equal to 0. Similarly it is not valid to show a message for values 2 and 200 if the Fee is not equal to 0.

Comment: Although this may answer the question, code-only answers are frowned upon.  Please also provide an explanation to OP to explain your answer.  [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)